# как добавить товар в избранное с помощью куки

Tags: javascript, cookie, javascript-events

Я прям совсем чайник и ни где не написано как это реализовать. Думал вообще через БД попробовать, но это же тогда придется добавлять авторизацию пользователей.

Comment: Вот есть статья по работе с куками... https://snipp.ru/jquery/cookie-js  Но если "прям чайник" - не факт что осилишь.

Comment: Спасибо, а есть на подобии как можно настроить просмотр сохраненных кук?

Comment: А для чего вам именно куки? Чем localStorage не подходит, если все равно собираетесь хранить на клиенте?

Comment: Читаешь и смотришь... Вроде не сложная наука.

Comment: Так в localStorage нельзя же хранить объекты